# Manage Desktop Profiles Gnome or XFCE

Tags: user-management, desktop, gnome, linux

I just set up a virtual machine for our software developers an now try to create the user accounts facing the following question:

Is there any possibility to distribute predefined desktop profiles with a certain software/ui configuration?
I recently used Sabayon for Gnome on another machine but it is not supported anymore.

I'm interested in a solution either for Gnome or XFCE on the latest Ubuntu 12.04.

Thanks for your replies.

Comment: How about a simple list of packages that you automatically `apt-get` on each machine. Tow along some GNOME config fies for the ride, stuff it into a zip with a custom shell script, and bingo!

Comment: it's just one machine with multiple users
i'll try to find out more about custom shell scripts :)

Comment: In that case, all of the apps will be shared anyway. As for settings, again, you should just be able to use some config-file copying.

Comment: with the information from http://serverfault.com/questions/407420/placeholder-for-later-username-in-etc-skel I managed to build my custom adduser.local to customize adduser to my needs

Comment: Good. If that solved your problem, you want to answer your question so people know it's solved and can benefit from your experience.

Answer (score 2):

The following steps solved my problems:

1. Created a default user and set everything up the way I wanted to. Configured bookmarks in my browser, added the local Jabber account, Shortcuts, Panels etc.
2. Copied the config folders and files like e.g. ~/.mozilla for firefox or ~/.purple for pidgin and the ~/.config/xfce4 directory for the XFCE setup into /etc/skel/ where all files are located that will be copied to a new user's home directory.
3. Replaced every time the username of my default user occured in the copied config files with ##USERNAME_REPLACE##
4. Created /usr/local/sbin/adduser.local what is automatically executed when "adduser" is called.
5. Wrote some substitution bash scripts that replace ##USERNAME_REPLACE## with the name of the newly created user. (Parameter $1 when adduser.local ist called by adduser.)
6. Because I use apache2-mpm-itk I need to add a vhost to the webserver configuration and one subdomain (username.localhost) per user to the /etc/hosts. Therefore I wrote a bash script that does the trick.
7. Finally after I set up the whole automation scripts they had to be called from adduser.local with the username (Parameter $1) of newly created users.

Everytime I call e.g. "adduser test_user" adduser.local is executed and does a wonderful setup so I can relax until everything is in place.
Important for me was, that adduser.local does not have to be a pearl script like the example files found on the system.

Hope it helps some others though.