# placeholder for later username in /etc/skel

Tags: linux, ubuntu, users, template, xubuntu

Is there any possibility to use a placeholder in the config files located in /etc/skel that is replaced by the username later?

e.g. I place ":USER:" in one config file and create a new user with the username "test". Then ":USER:" should be replaced by "test".

Thanks for your replies.

Comment: What distro?  Different distros do different things.

Comment: xubuntu 12.04 is in use

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ubuntu uses `adduser` from Debian, and that program just does a straight up file copy from `/etc/skel`, so you're out of luck there.  However, it does support hook scripts (look in `adduser`(8) for `adduser.local`), and you could write a little hook script that did a `sed -i` over some or all of the files in the newly-created home directory to do your text substitution magic.

Comment: I did `cp /usr/share/doc/adduser/examples/adduser.local /usr/local/sbin/`

Where in adduser.local do I have to place the search and replace code? I'm not quite familiar with perl syntax.

Comment: `adduser.local` doesn't have to be a Perl script.

Comment: that's great and how do I get the username parameter from adduser within the bash script?

Comment: I'm able to get the parameter by $1 but that does not have to be the username if additionally flags are used.
Do I have to check each parameter if it begins with a "-"? There has to be a more comfortable solution.

Comment: From `adduser`(8): "The arguments passed to adduser.local are: `username uid gid home-directory`".  Documentation is a *wonderful* thing.

Comment: thanks a lot, your made my day
read the documentation too but was irritated because i tested `adduser.local -n username` - sorry for that ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of environment variables directly within your shell init scripts.  For initialization files interpreted/used by other tools, refer to their methods.

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin/
```

... would add the user's home directory to their path (you might want to do some sanity checks such as that the directory exists first).

See "Shell Variables" within the `bash(1)` manpage for a list of variables defined/used by bash.

It would help if you'd clarify specifically what you're trying to do, and why.

Answer (score 0):

I got some useraccount crash thing here, so I'm posting from a new registered account here. Sorry for that.

I Did the following: https://serverfault.com/a/407613/128083

Made it "community wiki" so everyone can add his or her idea how to do it better.